# Free space not reclaimed after deleting large disk image from ext4 partition

Tags: backup, disk-usage

I have a 1TB backup disk with an ext4 partition on it where I keep disk images of my two disks - one is 500GB/466GiB (my main disk) and the other is 400GiB (data partition from my second disk). I use the GNOME Disks app for creating these images.

Problem:

After I deleted the 400GiB image from the backup disk I can't make a new backup image because there is not enough space left! I didn't send it to trash or something, I used `rm` to delete the file.

`df` shows that there is only 52G available:

```
df . -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdd1       917G  866G   52G  95% /media/szx/backup
```

`ls` gives only two files and `lost+found`:

```
ls -a .
.  ..  lost+found  msres.img  sda.img
```

`du` says that only 467GiB is used:

```
sudo du . -h
16K     ./lost+found
467G    .
```

Where did the remaining 932 - 467 = 465 GiB go?

I have disabled journaling and reduced reserved space to 0% using `tune2fs` for the backup partition to get as much free space as possible. It did free up some space but not all of it.

Comment: I'd imagine some process is still using that file. `lsof` would probably help finding that process. Did you restart after you deleted the file?

Comment: @wvxvw Yes, I did restart many times. I usually do backups from a live USB, but now I"m in the actual system on disk, so no process can be using something I think.

Comment: And no `.Trash-1000` folder too?

Comment: @George Seems so. I re-formatted the disk again but as ext2 this time. Maybe that will work better...